# Does android support all .ttf fonts?

Tags: fonts, xamarin.android

I recently created a Xamarin forms application and in my custom entry view renderer I attempted to display 4 different .ttf fonts I pulled from my windows 10 desktop...the fonts fonts were webding, Wingdings, ar decode, and another font(I don’t remember the name)...the only one that worked was ar decode. Which brings me to the question:”do all true type fonts work on android?”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android docs don't specify the fonts that it supports. When Android dislikes a custom font, rather than raising an Exception, it seems to substitute Droid Sans ("sans"). TTF is always been supported. OTF was later added at least in 1.6 and later, but partially. Some TTF fonts Android doesn't like.
For the same reason Android Simply substitutes it as mentioned above without even caring about whats going on

Comment: I guess my next question is if I create a true type font, how can I be assured it will render? Is there a special way/special tool to use to ensure it will meet google guidelines?

Comment: That is what I was saying k Android is unpredictable you cannot be sure if it will work